# How to get modified filter value in ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

i just started ag-grid, I have created grid with employeename and employeeno as column fields in grid,in grid employeeno column if filter get modify or selected need to get selected employee from filter.
as document suggested used **onFilterModified** ,function is calling but i want to get employeeno selected in filter.

my grid option as below---

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        angularCompileRows : true,
        angularCompileHeaders : true,
        columnDefs : columnDefs,
        debug : false,
        suppressMenuColumnPanel:true,
        suppressRowClickSelection:true,
        floatingTopRowData : createData(),
        rowData : null,
        rowHeight : 35,
        headerHeight : 35,
        enableFilter : true,
        enableSorting : true,
        enableColResize : true,
        rowSelection: 'multiple',
        onGridReady : function(event) {
            event.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
        },
        onFilterModified : callFilterModified
    };

 function callFilterModified(){
      alert("test")
  }
```

please give some suggestion over this.

Comment: Are you expecting to get one specific row? or are you trying to get what is put into the filter textbox?

Comment: my requirement something like below link and i resolve by writing custom filter.thanks for response.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489440/how-to-filter-with-choices-in-ag-grid/41182161#41182161

Comment: @Basavaraj, Have you found any solution for your problem? I am facing the similar issue.

Comment: @Kanan,i have created custom filter check below url                                   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489440/how-to-filter-with-choices-in-ag-grid/41182161#41182161

Comment: @JarodMoser Is it possible to get what is there in the filter textbox? I want to get the length of text entered?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to `filterChanged`, it should hook you up just after the filter data has been updated

```
this.gridOptions.api.getFilterInstance(filtername)
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/

Answer (score 0):

You will get all applied filters from api with getFilterModel() event. This will return all the applied filters with column name and if any condition is applied also.

To update other filter use setFilterModel().

Refer below link for more

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-api/